# el usuario debe ingrese 50 números enteros utilizando C

Tags: c

Como hago con código que le pida al usuario que ingrese 50 números enteros. Luego debe analizar números impares, promedios de números pares, número máximo y numero mínimo, y porcentaje de números menores que 50.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int n;

    printf("Introduzca un numero entero: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
        while (n != 0){
            printf("Introduzca un numero entero: ");
            scanf("%d", &n);
```

eso es lo que logre hasta ahora

Comment: perdon si es esta mal explicado, pero recién empiezo en programación es la primera vez que uso stack, y esa es la consigna que me pidieron. No tengo mucha práctica asi que me cuesta llevar a cabo estas tareas

Comment: Si eres nueva, te recomiendo que hagas el
[recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para saber como funciona el
sitio. Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Que hace ese codigo que agregaste? donde intentas hacer el resto de las cosas?

Comment: hasta ahora lo que logre es que el usuario ingrese por pantalla los números que se le pide, lo que debería lograr ahora es que una vez que ingrese los 50 números, se termine y luego analizar esos números ingresados

Answer (score 1):

Veo algunos fallos en tu programa:

1. Debes cerrar las llaves de `main` y `while`
2. Revisa la condición del `while`, ya que según está escrito se seguirán ingresando números hasta que uno sea '0'.
3. Para detectar números pares e impares te recomiendo que eches un vistazo al operador `%` https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm

Sería bastante fácil para todos ponerte la solución aquí mismo, pero el fin de este foro es resolver dudas siempre y cuando se hayan trabajado un poco por parte del publicador, no que se te hagan los deberes sin ningún esfuerzo ([¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2868/por-qu%c3%a9-he-recibido-un-voto-negativo/4320#4320)).

Coméntanos qué errores te dan, qué has pensado hacer... y podremos ayudarte.

Un saludo.

Comment: no estoy pidiendo que solucionen todo el código, lo único que necesito es saber es como luego de ingresados los 50 números se cierra el bucle. Lamentablemente me tocaron profesores que han explicado como se debía y dieron por entendido que sabemos programar siendo que es nuestro primer curso de programación. Hago lo que puedo mirando videos en internet, entiendo algunos conceptos pero me cuesta aplicarlos.

Comment: Entiendo la frustración. Yo también pasé por esa situación en la que me dieron mi primera clase sin yo haber programado en mi vida. Te comento algunas pistas que te puedan hacer pensar. (i) Tienes que pensar un modo de romper el bucle `while`, ya que según lo tienes sólo saldrá cuando `n` sea distinto de '0' (contadores). (ii) Te recomiendo tapar todas las posibilidades del programa que no contemplas, como por ejemplo que se introduzca un número decimal, un carácter que no sea un número entero, etc. (usa if-else).

Comment: **CONTINUACIÓN** (iii) Para almacenar los números enteros te recomiendo usar arrays. (iv) Primero céntrate en recoger todos los datos (números enteros en este caso), y una vez que los tengas comienza a operar con ellos: obtener el promedio, pares/impares, máximo/mínimo, etc. **CONSEJO** Yo también empecé sin tener ni idea de programar. Intenta pedir audiencia con tu profesor, alegando que no tienes mucha idea de programar, lo entenderá porque nadie nace sabiendo, pero deberás trabajar a partes iguales que tu profesor te ayuda. Espero que te sirva de ayuda. Un saludo.